# Log In With PayPal button duplicates twice or even three times in React

Tags: reactjs, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I've been setting up Log In With PayPal using React/Redux on the front end.

The span with id "lippbutton" renders, but for some reason I have started to see a minimum of two buttons showing up inline.  If I inspect, I see "lippbutton" as a parent and two or three paypal buttons as children, each with their own unique paypal-assigned id.

Anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening?

```
   export default class PayPalLoginButton extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
        }
        render() {   
                paypal.use( ['login'], function (login) {
                  login.render ({
                    "appid":"myappid",
                    "authend":"sandbox",
                    "scopes":"openid profile address email",
                    "containerid":"lippButton",
                    "locale":"en-us",
                    "returnurl":"http://localhost:8080/paypal",
                    "text": 'Sign Up With PayPal'
                  });
                }); 
                return (
                <span id='lippButton'></span>
                );

        }
    }
```

Comment: You should probably move the `paypal.use()`. code into the `componentDidMount()` method.  As it is, that code is being called each time the component renders (and the `lippButton` div might not even exist when you call `paypal.use()`

Comment: Thanks so much! Seems to have worked like a charm.